# D3 Stacked Bar Chart stack height issue

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am new to D3. I am working through a current example. What I am trying to do is plot the stacked barchart for the given data.

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "ABC",
    "total": 4,
    "used": 1,
    "type": "Unused"
  },
  {
    "name": "ABC",
    "total": 4,
    "used": 1,
    "type": "Used"
  },
  {
    "name": "PQR",
    "total": 3,
    "used": 1,
    "type": "Unused"

  },
  {
    "name": "PQR",
    "total": 3,
    "used": 1,
    "type": "Used"
  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "total": 2,
    "used": 1,
    "type": "Unused"

  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "total": 2,
    "used": 1,
    "type": "Used"
  },
  {
    "name": "LMN",
    "total": 1,
    "used": 0,
    "type": "Unused"

  },
  {
    "name": "LMN",
    "total": 1,
    "used": 0,
    "type": "Used"

  },
  {
    "name": "OPQ",
    "total": 1,
    "used": 0,
    "type": "Unused"


  },
  {
    "name": "OPQ",
    "total": 1,
    "used": 0,
    "type": "Used"
  },

]
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 60,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,

  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");


var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#fff", "#F18111"]);

var stack = d3.stack()
  .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
  .offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand);



data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.unused = d.total - d.used
});

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.name;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.total
})]);
// z.domain(["used", "unused"]);

var serie = g.selectAll(".serie")
  .data(stack.keys(["used", "unused"])(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "serie")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("opacity", "0.9");

serie.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.data.name);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .text(function(d) {
    return y(d.data.total)
  })


// gridlines in y axis function
function make_y_gridlines() {
  return d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(10)
}


// add the Y gridlines
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_gridlines()
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickFormat("")
  )
  .attr("opacity", "0.1")

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width='600' height='300'></svg>
```

I want the stacked bar for "used" and "unused" for a particular data. Somehow I am getting the stacks, but the height of the stacks are not proper and more over the size of stacks for "used" and "unused" is interchanged and not according to the data.

I tried changing the values in .attr("height") but nothing worked.

Comment: Do you really need to set the stack offset to d3.stackOffsetExpand? By applying this, the sum of series will be normalized to a value of 1.

Comment: You've applied the stackOffsetExpand which is normalizing your stack to 1. Remove the offset and you should be good.
https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#stackOffsetExpand

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked but now the only problem is I need the bar of "used" on top of stack but its inverse right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Removed the stack offset, which will remove the normalization.
- To change the order of stack, change the order of keys while binding data. 
  `.data(stack.keys(["unused", "used"])(data))`

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 60,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,

  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");


var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#fff", "#F18111"]);

var stack = d3.stack()
  .order(d3.stackOrderNone);

var data = [{
    "name": "ABC",
    "total": 4,
    "used": 1,
    "type": "Unused"
  },

  {
    "name": "PQR",
    "total": 3,
    "used": 1,
    "type": "Unused"

  },

  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "total": 2,
    "used": 1,
    "type": "Unused"

  },

  {
    "name": "LMN",
    "total": 1,
    "used": 0,
    "type": "Unused"

  },

  {
    "name": "OPQ",
    "total": 1,
    "used": 0,
    "type": "Unused"


  }

];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.unused = d.total - d.used
});

//console.log(data);

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.name;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.total
})]);
// z.domain(["used", "unused"]);

var serie = g.selectAll(".serie")
  .data(stack.keys(["unused", "used"])(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "serie")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("opacity", "0.9");

serie.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.data.name);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .text(function(d) {
    return y(d.data.total)
  })


// gridlines in y axis function
function make_y_gridlines() {
  return d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(10)
}


// add the Y gridlines
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_gridlines()
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickFormat("")
  )
  .attr("opacity", "0.1")

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width=800 height=500></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm